# ¿Cómo validar un TextEdit para que sólo admita el ingreso de números en el builder C++?

Tags: c++

He tenido dificultades con un ejercicio en Visual C++, les pido que por favor me ayuden.
Necestito una forma eficiente de realizar una validación a un TextEdit, para almacenar en una variable tanto double como entera pero evitar la entrada de datos string o char.

Answer (score 0):

Después de desgastar la lógica, encontré la solución.

Algo sencillo, simplemente en el evento "OnKeyPress" coloqué este fragmento de código.

/*
if (Key !='\b' && Key !='0' && Key !='1' && Key !='2' && Key !='3' && Key !='4' && Key !='5' && Key !='6' && Key !='7' && Key !='8' && Key !='9')

{

Key = 0;

}
*/

Gracias de todos modos...